# Difference between twitter share buttons

Tags: html, api, twitter, social-networking

I simply want to add couple share button onto my page. And I see that people recommend different ways of doing it:

I see some articles using `home?status`:

```
<a href=”http://twitter.com/home?status=Currently reading <?php the_permalink(); ?>” title=”Click to send this page to Twitter!” target=”_blank” rel=”nofollow”>Share on Twitter</a>
```

and some using `share?url`:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button" target="_blank">Tweet</a>
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example simply updates the status with the text you enter. The second example has a lot more functionality.

`share?url` supports class attributes for the anchor tag. In the anchor tag you can add things like `data-related` to suggest accounts the user will follow after they share the content or if you don't supply a url it will look for the current url the call is being generated from and share that. It has a lot more functionality vs the dumbed down `home?status` call.

find more here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button